# Rails 4.1 inconsistent GET requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, get

When requesting a page from rails I get strange behaviours.

Calling on `<%= link_to "Start »", '/app', role: "button" %>` the first time will get me to the view without loading ANY asset except for one js file included at the bottom of the layout (after `</body>`). This results in an ugly und functional page.

```
Started GET "/app" for 10.0.2.2 at 2014-05-08 16:09:51 +0000
Processing by AppController#index as HTML
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Authentication Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "authentications".* FROM "authentications"  WHERE "authentications"."user_id" = $1  ORDER BY "authentications"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 1]]
  Rendered app/_google_maps.html.erb (11.3ms)
  Rendered app/index.html.erb within layouts/application (45.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 886ms (Views: 129.4ms | ActiveRecord: 2.7ms)


Started GET "/assets/app.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at 2014-05-08 16:09:52 +0000
```

Calling it the second time will get the results I would normally expect - loading the page with all its elements.

```
Started GET "/app" for 10.0.2.2 at 2014-05-08 16:10:56 +0000
Processing by AppController#index as HTML
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Authentication Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "authentications".* FROM "authentications"  WHERE "authentications"."user_id" = $1  ORDER BY "authentications"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 1]]
  Rendered app/_google_maps.html.erb (13.7ms)
  Rendered app/index.html.erb within layouts/application (35.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 561ms (Views: 111.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.9ms)


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap.min.css?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at 2014-05-08 16:10:57 +0000


Started GET "/assets/jquery.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at 2014-05-08 16:10:57 +0000


Started GET "/assets/app.css?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at 2014-05-08 16:10:57 +0000


Started GET "/assets/application.css?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at 2014-05-08 16:10:57 +0000


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap-slider.css?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at 2014-05-08 16:10:57 +0000


Started GET "/assets/font-awesome.min.css?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at 2014-05-08 16:10:57 +0000


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap.min.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at 2014-05-08 16:10:57 +0000


Started GET "/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at 2014-05-08 16:10:57 +0000


Started GET "/assets/turbolinks.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at 2014-05-08 16:10:57 +0000


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap-slider.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at 2014-05-08 16:10:57 +0000


Started GET "/assets/application.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at 2014-05-08 16:10:57 +0000


Started GET "/assets/app.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at 2014-05-08 16:10:57 +0000
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Read about turbolinks

Comment: Thank you Michael, that was it!

Comment: Instead of disabling turbo links altogether you may take a look at  https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks

Comment: This is actually what I've done: `<%= link_to "Start »", app_path, data: { no_turbolink: true } %>`since it's logically the first link the user will have to click to get to that page. After that it's all turbolinks. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Michael suggested in the comments it was a turbo link. So, what I did was adding `data-no-turbolink=true` to the anchor like so: `<%= link_to "Start »", app_path, data: { no_turbolink: true } %>` - that solved my problem.

**Edit:**

Better solution:
`<body data-no-turbolink=true>`

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't solve any problem, it will occur again with another page. You either need to remove turbo links or learn to use them properly.

Comment: Hi Michael, it doesn't generally solve the problem, but in my case it's enough, since only the one controller/view requires the "whole package" of javascript.

Comment: That's ok, what I am pointing out to is you may need it in the future and forget about this "hack" and this will lead to another investigation.